# How to change background color for a specific portion of window (Python) (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, window

I just wanted to know how you could **change the background color of window for a specific portion only**, instead of changing the whole window's color.

[Like This (MS Paint)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc7Vy.png)

Comment: Are you going to have some widgets that are over both at the same time (ie: straddling the line between the two colors)?

Comment: I've coded it using Grid Widgets...

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question

Comment: yea, i do have some widgets on my window...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what else your window has in it, the simplest solution is to create two frames, one for each section. You can then use `place` to place the two widgets in the window without affecting the layout of any other widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
red_frame = tk.Frame(bd=0, highlightthickness=0, background="red")
blue_frame = tk.Frame(bd=0, highlightthickness=0, background="blue")
red_frame.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0, relheight=.5, anchor="nw")
blue_frame.place(x=0, rely=.5, relwidth=1.0, relheight=.5, anchor="nw")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I mean, it worked on what i asked for, but now the label widgets stands on top(the labels doesn't merge with the background color) and has their own color surrounding them...

Answer (score 0):

Create a background image by using this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
top = Tk()

C = Canvas(top, bg="blue", height=250, width=300)
filename = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\location\\imageName.png")
background_label = Label(top, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

C.pack()
top.mainloop
```

Find an image online that suits your needs and your ready to go; another option is making an image and saving it locally and using that.

Get back to me if it didn't work or you need anymore help.
-Jack

Comment: Also I've Coded a full program using Grids (.grid)

Comment: Cool, that sounds like a better solution